# Error 503: Service Unavaiable but localhost works perfectly

Tags: php

I have a simple code

```
<?php
    echo "Test Message";
?>
```

The name of the file is test.php
This works fine when i access this code using localhost/test.php    My computer has a local network IP 114.122.23.31. When I try access it using 114.122.23.31/test.php it shows: 503 Service Unavailable Failed to connect to server 114.122.23.31. I check the apache access log and find

127.0.0.1 - - [18/Apr/2012:12:00:08 +0530] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 19 ---- when I access it using localhost.

127.0.0.1 - - [18/Apr/2012:11:58:30 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 18902 ----- when I access it using IP. Please help. 
PS: It was working fine yesterday. Donno what happened today :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your ip changed from yesterday because the dhcp lease expired?
Is your server configured to accept connections on non-localhost ips?

Comment: Is your server configured to accept connections on non-localhost ips? Yes, since I was accessing this URL from other local area computers too. The IP shown in the TCP/IP properties is same. How do I check about the DHCP being expired?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem, I couldn't start localhost through Xampp and it shows error 503. But I have solved it by stopping service that use port 80 on IIS. Follow these steps:

1. Start
2. Right Click on My Computer
3. Click Manage
4. Click Services and Applications
5. Click Internet Information Service (IIS) Manager
6. On Block IIS, find HTTP Redirect and HTTP Respond Header, stop that service by right clicking.
7. Try to start Apache through Xampp Control Panel again.

Hope it help.

Thank.